# React Native: ListView item does not scale full width

Tags: listview, react-native

I create a simple ListView component with a simple Text item.

```js
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ListView } from "react-native";

export default class NoteList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => {
        r1 !== r2;
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.ds.cloneWithRows([
          { title: "Note 1", body: "Body 1", id: 1 },
          { title: "Note 2", body: "Body 2", id: 2 }
        ])}
        renderRow={rowData => {
          return (
            <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.itemText}>
                {rowData.title}
              </Text>
            </View>
          );
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  itemContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    borderColor: "red",
    borderWidth: 1
  },

  itemText: {
    padding: 16,
    borderColor: "blue",
    borderWidth: 1
  }
});
```

I use a wrapper View for a Text. Then use FlexBox to scale the Text to full width and align its content to the left. But the result is not as expected when the Text was aligned center and wrap content (the wrapper view also wrap content). How to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean to create component `text` to full width ?

Comment: try this it's working for me [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48270297/7516620)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `flex` on style `itemText` like :

```
itemText: {

    flex: 1,
    padding: 16,
    borderColor: "blue",
    borderWidth: 1

}
```

in my emulator show like :

[image]

i hope my answer can help you..

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Dimensions` as well, to get width of screen and assign to `text`

Import Dimensions from react-native

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ListView, Dimensions } from "react-native";
```

assign `width` to `text`:

```
itemText: {
    padding: 16,
    borderColor: "blue",
    borderWidth: 1,
    width: (Dimensions.get('window').width)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-easy-grid](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-easy-grid), it will be easy to design in such cases

Implemented example:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ListView } from "react-native";
import {Col} from 'react-native-easy-grid';
 // 0.1.15

export default class NoteList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => {
        r1 !== r2;
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.ds.cloneWithRows([
          { title: "Note 1", body: "Body 1", id: 1 },
          { title: "Note 2", body: "Body 2", id: 2 }
        ])}
        renderRow={rowData => {
          return (
            <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
              <Col>
              <Text style={styles.itemText}>
                {rowData.title}
              </Text>
              </Col>
            </View>
          );
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  itemContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    borderColor: "red",
    borderWidth: 1
  },

  itemText: {
    padding: 16,
    borderColor: "blue",
    borderWidth: 1
  }
});
```