# React Native: Flex: 1 does not fill width of parent

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I'm using ListItem imported from native-base. ListItem is red and it's child View is yellow. As you can see from the screenshot, View style does not take entire width of ListItem, despite having a flex: 1. How can I make it so that View take entire width of ListItem?

[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjPm1.png)

```
 <List>
<ListItem style={[styles.listitem, { backgroundColor: "red" }]}>
    <View
        style={{
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: "column",
            backgroundColor: "yellow"
        }}
    >
        <Text style={styles.timeInfoHeader}>{this.props.totalUsage}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.timeInfoSubHeader}>Total (hrs)</Text>
    </View>
</ListItem>
</List>;
```

Stylesheet:

```
  timeInfoHeader: {
    fontSize: 40,
    color: 'rgba(45, 145, 176, 100)',
    textAlign: 'center'
  },

  timeInfoSubHeader: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: 'rgba(209, 209, 209, 100)',
    paddingBottom: 4,
    marginBottom: 4,
    textAlign: 'center'
  },

  listitem: {
    width: '100%',
    marginLeft: 0
  },
```

Comment: what if you try `width:100%`

Comment: That didnt work. I guess that when I did flex: 1 in View it supposedly taken 100% of the width. I also checked that there was no padding on ListItem

Comment: and what about `List` ?

Comment: No, that didn't do it either.

Comment: It looks that there is a padding on ListItem.

Comment: @AlexandreAnnic I set padding to 0, still the same. There was no padding.

Comment: A margin to the view so ? With the chrome debugger it should be easy to indentify the problem.

Comment: try to add `margin:0;paddin:0` to all the item to be sure there is no default one added

Comment: Actually it was a padding issue. I previously removed the padding and it didn't work. I guess it didn't save properly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
listitem: {
   marginLeft: 0,
   flex:1,
   paddingRight: 0
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just add `width: '100%'` on your view's styles.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this -
`flexGrow: 1`

Hope it helped someone =)

Answer (score 2):

**Try this code snippet:**

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }} >
<View style={{ flex: 1 }} >
...
</View >
</ScrollView >
```

Comment: that didn't solve it for me. No change

Answer (score 0):

What causes this is the `textAlign` style on the `timeInfoHeader`. So you can either remove the `textAlign` style from `timeInfoHeader` or add a `width: "100%"` to `listitem`. Just glancing at your code, it seems you might be better off adding the `textAlign` to the child View of `timeInfoHeader`.